# How can I convince eclipse/JUnit4 to find all my tests, in a gradle/eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, junit

### Background

JUnit 4 test runner, within Eclipse 4.11.

I have an eclipse project that was imported from a build.gradle file.  This project has several different source paths, each with their own test path.
main/java, test/java, foo/java, fooTest/java, fooTest/resource, and so on.

### Problem

When I run a "whole project" JUnit configuration (debug, run, code coverage, whatever), all it finds are the tests within "test/java".  I have successfully added new test classes and new `@Test` methods within this folder.

Tests from any other source path are ignored when I try to "Run all tests in the selected project, package, or source folder".  Furthermore, selecting the specific source folder 'fooTest/java' errors out with the message "No tests found with test runner 'Junit 4'".  **However**, when I use the "Run a single test" option with a specific test class, it finds all its test methods just fine.  I can specify a particular method and the test runs just fine.

### Stuff that didn't work

I tried changing the output directories of my non-main test source paths to write to the same folder as my working test source path.  No joy.

I tried various settings of Eclipse's "Contains test sources" flag for my different test source paths.  On or off, the behavior is the same across all my test source paths.  `/test/java` is always found, `fooTest/java` is always missed.  No, I haven't tried all 16 permutations of the flag across my 4 different test source paths.

I tried ripping out all the gradle-related stuff from the .project and .classpath.  No change in behavior.  Dammit... got my hopes up.

I tried changing the order of the `<classpathentry/>` in the `.classpath` project file.  When I moved `test/java` such that it was no longer the first test path, I once again got the "no tests found" error, just like when I aimed the junit configuration "run all tests in the selected project, package, or source folder" at one of my other test source folders.  Putting it back restored the original behavior.

---

Does anyone have further suggestions I could try to make my remaining tests run without individual configurations for every test class that I must manually run one at a time?

Comment: How are you running tests? Eclipse launcher, gradle task?

Comment: I run them via the eclipse runner... either by clicking 'debug' or 'run' in the UI, or by pressing F11 or ctrl+F11 (which do the same things respectively).  The gradle tasks are already separated out by "source set", and I can (and do) provide multiple tasks at the command line... but Eclipse just has the "whole project" option, but it's not working as advertised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to the JUnit 5 test runner, and it picked up on everything just fine.  It's vintage package was able to find all my JUnit 4 tests, and I've since modified several tests to use the newfangled annotations and Assertions in JUnit 5.

Perhaps this was a known bug/limitation in the JUnit 4 runner?  Ah well.  It works now.